# what's the difference between kotlin main functions

Tags: kotlin, syntax

what's the difference between this two types of main function in kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Hello World!")
}
```

and

```
fun main() {
    print("Hello World!")
}
```

Comment: https://www.javaprogramto.com/2020/04/kotlin-main-function-fun-examples.html

Comment: If you want to pass parameters to your programme from outside, you need the array specification.  Since Kotlin 1.3, you can also omit this parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax with the args is used to pass the parameters to the module from command line interface or from outside program. If you don't need it, you can omit it.

If you are getting started with kotlin I strongly recommend you to look at [kotlin official website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html).

Comment: It seems you are new to StackOverflow, as a practice consider upvoting the answers that helped you so that others can find them more easily. Welcome and Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

With the first option you could pass arguments when running your program